# Reset Undo/Redo Array iOS

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, nsundomanager

I want to undo and redo the strokes and changes in a drawing app, using NSUndoManager.
I am storing the image using UIGraphicsGetImagefromCurrentImageContext() onto a mutable array.

My Code below gives an idea:

```
- (void) performUndoRedo:(BOOL) undo
{
    if (undo)
    {
        [undoManager undo];
    }
    else
    {
        [undoManager redo];
    }

    NSLog(@"layerArray:%@", layerArray);

    [self drawImage:[layerArray lastObject]];
}

- (void) redo:(id) object
{
    [layerArray addObject:object];
    [[undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] undo:object];
    [undoManager setActionName:@"drawredo"];
    // NSLog(@"layerArray IN REDO:%@", layerArray);
}

- (void) undo:(id) object
{
    [[undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] redo:object];
    [undoManager setActionName:@"drawundo"];
    [layerArray removeObject:object];
    // NSLog(@"layerArray IN UNDO:%@", layerArray);
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *layerImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    [layerArray addObject:layerImage];
    [self undo:layerImage];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSLog(@"%@", layerArray);
}
```

How and at what point of action can I clear the layerArray, and reset the undo stack? Thanks in advance

Comment: whether you succeeded in Undo Redo operations

Comment: Did u found any solution for this. Am also facing this same issue. It would be helpful for me if anyone have idea on this.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you can use the methods in each of those classes for clearing:

- `layerArray` is an [`NSMutableArray`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

  - From the docs for [`removeAllObjects`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/removeAllObjects)

> Empties the array of all its elements.

`undoManager` is an [`NSUndoManagaer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUndoManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

- From the docs for [`removeAllActions`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUndoManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUndoManager/removeAllActions):

> Clears the undo and redo stacks and re-enables the receiver.

Comment: My question is when should I reset the NSUndoManager and NSMutableArray?

Comment: Hmm, that's not how your question above reads: first line is "I want to reset", not "When should I reset". I'm not clear on what the actual problem is: does your undo stack have actions in there that are unwanted? Put another way: why do you want to reset it?

Comment: The layerArray keeps on growing when I log. I need a way to clear that  array, when another set of actions replaces the previous action in the  undo stack.